# Error: Typed property must not be accessed before initialization

Tags: laravel, queue, load-balancing, broadcast

When I try to use `broadcast (...)`, in the table `failed_jobs` I get the error:

> Error: Typed property App\Events\SendMessageEvent:: $ message must not be accessed before initialization in app/Events/SendMessageEvent.php:49

I call `broadcast (...)` like this:

```
public function send(MessageDto $dto): Message
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        /** @var Message $message */
        $message = Message::factory()
            ->create([
                'from' => $dto->from,
                'toid' => $dto->toid,
                'tema' => $dto->tema ?? null,
                'text' => $dto->text,
                'data' => Carbon::now(),
                'opdata' => Carbon::now()->timestamp,
                'ip' => request()->ip()
            ]);

        DB::commit();

        if ($message) {
            broadcast(new SendMessageEvent($message))->toOthers();
        }

        return $message;
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        DB::rollBack();
        throw $exception;
    }
}
```

##### `SendMessageEvent` implementation

```php
class SendMessageEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public ?array $message = [];

    private int $to;

    public bool $afterCommit = true;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->to = $message->toid;
        $this->message = [
            'id' => $message->id,
            'from' => $message->from,
            'to' => $message->toid,
            'content' => $message->text,
            'date' => $message->data,
            'read' => $message->read,
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return PrivateChannel[]
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel(sprintf('message.%s', $this->to))
        ];
    }
}
```

The message is correctly written to the database, the error periodically occurs only when the queue is running.

The application works through the load balancer, there is an error in line 49, but at the same time in the `SendMessageEvent.php` file there are only 49 lines and line number 49 is `}`, this is a character that closes the class.

Please tell me what is the problem?

I tried to clean the cache:

- `php artisan optimize:clear`
- `php artisan clear-compiled`
- `composer dump-autoload`

I did this on all the servers behind the balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Add an initial `null` value to `$to` property:

```
private ?int $to = null;
```

You can read more about reason of this problem in this article: https://madewithlove.com/blog/typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initialization/

In short, defined type-hinted properties without initial values are in `undefined` state and it's never match any declared type, so when you trying to get its value, you'll get this error.

Error triggered because `$this->to` in `broadcastOn` method is `undefined`